# How to prevent Re-render in react when the state is changed using Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using functional components and React-Redux to manage state. Simply speaking, I hope that even if the state changes, rendering will not happen. First of all, the code is as follows. It is a simple code for explanation.

```
const NOUPDATE = ({ uploadAnswer, noState }) => (
  <>
    <div className="content">
      <div className="container">
        <p className="directions" />
        <ul className="qbox">{noState ? (<p>true</p>) : (<p>false</p>)}</ul>
        <button onClick={uploadAnswer}>upload</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </>
);
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  noState: state.problemInfoReducer.checkMode,
});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  uploadAnswer: value => dispatch(uploadAnswer(value)),
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(NOUPDATE);
```

uploadAnswer reverses noState each time it is dispatched. So if I dispatch uploadAnswer every time, noState is updated, and the screen is re-rendered as a whole. I don't want the screen to be re-rendered even if noState is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that allows you to keep the `qbox` boolean toggle without rendering the parent component. Essesntially, you use Redux to your advantage by creating a child component that's mapped to the `noState` property rather than having that mapping in the parent component.

NOUPDATE.jsx

```
import Qbox from "./Qbox";

const NOUPDATE = ({ uploadAnswer }) => (
  <>
    <div className="content">
      <div className="container">
        <p className="directions" />
        <Qbox />
        <button onClick={uploadAnswer}>upload</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </>
);

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  uploadAnswer: value => dispatch(uploadAnswer(value)),
});

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(NOUPDATE);
```

Qbox.jsx

```
const Qbox = ({noState}) => <ul className="qbox">{noState ? (<p>true</p>) : (<p>false</p>)}</ul>;

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  noState: state.problemInfoReducer.checkMode,
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(Qbox);
```

Comment: IT WORKS NICK! THANK YOU!

Comment: Hooray, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `React.memo` to memoize your component. The second argument passed to `React.memo` is a function that takes `oldProps` and `newProps`. Return `false` when the component should be updated.

Below, I return `false` only when the `uploadAnswer` doesn't match between `oldProps` and `newProps`, so that's the only time the component will re-render.

```
const NOUPDATE = React.memo(
  ({ uploadAnswer, noState }) => (
    <>
      <div className="content">
        <div className="container">
          <p className="directions" />
          <ul className="qbox">{noState ? <p>true</p> : <p>false</p>}</ul>
          <button onClick={uploadAnswer}>upload</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  ),
  (oldProps, newProps) => {
    if (oldProps.uploadAnswer !== newProps.uploadAnswer) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
);
```

Comment: thank you for your help! but I got additional question. As you can see, my 'qbox' class's p tag is not working. I only want to change p tag, true or false. Is it possible?

Comment: Hmm, I don't quite follow; what do you mean it's not working?

Comment: Well, I'd like to ask you in advance that I think it might be a pretty strange question. In my qbox, the contents of the p tag are either true or false according to noState. It's like a toggle button. But, of course, it doesn't work like a toggle button because it doesn't re-render.

Comment: Yes, that's going to be problematic! You can't have it both ways. What you can do is create a separate element that only takes `noState` and map that to `props` using Redux. You can then remove the `noState` prop dependency within this component.

Comment: I'm adding a new answer that should hopefully do what you're looking for